# Is subjectivity intrinsic to the definition of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Entropy is defined as a measure of order in the current positions and velocities of particles in a system. But isn't "order" subjective? For instance, suppose I sample four random letters and form the string "hwyl". That string could be disordered for one person but very ordered and meaningful to another. If we consider the set of pixels between the quotation marks above, do the particles in that system have lower entropy for an observer who knows the meaning of the word?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_and_disorder Trying to simplify "order" into strings of text doesn't really give clear metaphors.

Comment: Entropy is quantified in terms of the number of quantum mechanical equilibrium states that the system has access to, under the imposed constraints.  How does that relate to your pixels.